# Rails: how to add active class to high_voltage pages in navigation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my non-high_voltage pages, I'm useing the following code to add an "active" class to the navigation element if the user is on the page: `<li class="<%= 'active' if params[:controller] == 'home' %>"><a href="/">Home</a></li>`

What is the equivalent way of doing it for my high_voltage pages (I want the active class on the li)?

```
<li class="nav-item"><%= link_to 'Plans', page_path("plans") %></li>
```

Comment: Do you want this class on single, particular list item?

Comment: a specific list item. If I had an "about" page, I would want that list item to have the "active" class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with this:

```
<li class="nav-item <%= 'active' if page_path == '/about' %>">
  <%= link_to "About", page_path("about") %>
</li>
```

High voltage provides the `page_path` method to link to pages. I can use that to determine if I am on that page or not just like I do with the controller.

Comment: See my answer, just modified your answer to work with dynamic paths of pages

Answer (score 1):

You can use high_voltage's `page_path` function with `current_page?`

```
<li class='<%="active" if current_page?page_path('about') %>'>About</li>
<li class='<%="active" if current_page?page_path('contact') %>'>Contact</li>
```

Comment: thanks, it's a better solution than the accepted answer provided from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

As it is static page, you can just write it directly in HTML code:

```
<li class="active nav-item"><%= link_to 'Plans', page_path("plans") %></li>
```

Comment: i need the class to be on it only when the person is on the page. The class itself is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution that will keep the conditional logic out of your views and uses pure CSS to mark your active navigation items. It can be used with all your views including high_voltage pages.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def body_class
    "#{controller_name} #{controller_name}-#{controller.action_name} #{params['id']}"
  end

  def controller_name
    controller.controller_path.gsub('/','-')
  end
end
```

Call the helper method from the layout

```
<body class="<%= body_class %>">
```

This will give you a body class like this when on the `PagesController#show` with `id=plans`

```
<body class="pages pages-show plans">
```

The html for the navigation would look like this

```
<ul class="nav-items">
  <li class="home">Home</li>
  <li class="plans">Plans</li>
  <li class="contact">Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Then you can use CSS to target the nav item you'd like active

```
body.home li.home,
body.plans li.plans,
body.contact li.contact {
  // styles for active item
}
```